Error thrown when parsing returned values from a Graph SDK batch operation
I wrote a method to upload a document and update its corresponding list item in a batch.  I mostly copied code from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/batch-requests?tabs=csharp
When I execute the method, I see two updates instead of one:
version history
In addition, when I try to deserialize the SharePoint object returned from the batch, I get an error:
Status: 500
Response:
{"type":"JsonReaderException","message":"'e' is an invalid start of a value. LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 0.","stackTrace":"System.Text.Json.JsonReaderException: 'e' is an invalid start of a value. LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 0.\r\n
Here's the method I wrote today:
private static async Task BatchLoadItemsAsync(GraphServiceClient graphClient, string driveId, string driveItemId, ListItem currentListItem, ListItem listItemUpdate, byte[] stream)
{
    /* create the batch request collection */
    var batchRequestContent = new BatchRequestContentCollection(graphClient);
    
    /* define the steps */
    var driveItemRequest = graphClient.Drives[driveId].Items[driveItemId].Content.ToPutRequestInformation(new MemoryStream(stream));
    var listItemRequest = graphClient.Drives[driveId].List.Items[currentListItem.Id].ToPatchRequestInformation(listItemUpdate);

    /* add the steps to the batch request collection */
    var batchRequestStepId1 = await batchRequestContent.AddBatchRequestStepAsync(driveItemRequest);
    var batchRequestStepId2 = await batchRequestContent.AddBatchRequestStepAsync(listItemRequest);

    var returnedResponse = await graphClient.Batch.PostAsync(batchRequestContent);

    /* try to get the drive item and list item returned by the batch request collection */
    try
    {
        var newDriveItem = await returnedResponse.GetResponseByIdAsync<DriveItem>(batchRequestStepId1);
        var newListItem = await returnedResponse.GetResponseByIdAsync<ListItem>(batchRequestStepId2);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        var msg = ex.Message;
        throw;
    }
}

The returnedResponse indicates 200 (success) for each of the 2 steps.  The GetResponseByIdAsync methods in the try clause fail every time.
More importantly, though, I am using a batch operation to avoid having 2 versions of every document: one version for the updated file and one version for the updated list item.
Can anyone suggest next steps?  There is not much documentation out there on using batches in the Graph SDK but I am hopeful.
